# Having trouble getting my head around fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysqli

sorry but complete newbie to php and mysqli. I have this in my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT tutorial_title, tutorial_author FROM tutorial_info WHERE tutorial_id<=3;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if($result===FALSE) {

  echo "Select failed <br>";

}

else {

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "Tutorial Title: " . $row["tutorial_title"]. " - Name: " . $row["tutorial_author"]. "<br>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
```

This works fine but I don't understand how the line `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` works. From what I understand it fetches an array so I have something like `while($row=$somearray)`. Why does this iterate though all the rows though? Does `fetch_assoc()` have a loop built in that iterates though all the rows and returns one at a time?

Comment: var_dump($result->fetch_assoc() and you will see the array structure

Comment: It seems like the while move the cursor on every iteration. Like using `each($array)` in the while loop.

Comment: All that is inside brackets is an `expression` so when `fetch_assoc()` returns `null` the whole expression is also becomes `null` and the loop breaks.

Comment: @frz3993 Not `while` moves the cursor but `fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Mind to elaborate @kulaeff ?

Comment: @kulaeff so is fetch_assoc retuning one array at a time (i.e one for each row found in the select statement)?

Answer (score 0):

THere are different answer but one is: 
`mysqli_fetch_assoc` — Fetch a result row as an associative array.
Also, *Returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.*

Read [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) in detail.